# Electrical safety best practices for a transformer secondary

Tags: transformer, safety

If I'm building something with a transformer that has mains on the primary and something like 24VAC, or just any voltage lower than mains on the secondary, what are the best practices in terms of electrical safety to prevent electrical shock and fire?

Comment: Is this a one-off (hobby project or special device for a lab or whatever) or a potential commercial project? What are the total power requirements? Any chance you can just use an off-the-shelf plug-in power supply that connects to mains on one side and presents low-voltage AC or DC on the other side, with a nice insulated box in between?

Answer (score 1):

Most smaller plug-in transformers have a thermal fuse in the primary circuit. When building contactor panels, larger transformers (80 VA and up) usually require a fused primary.